# Use ethernet and wifi simultaneously for better ping and speed on windows 10

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, ethernet, ping

I know that using **ethernet** and **wifi** is possible on windows 10, but I don't know if it will solve my problem. I need fast internet for my work, as well as good ping for games and what video calls.

The problem is that my pc is far away from the router and that I can't run lan cables through the hole house,  that's why I use a wifi adapter. With it I can download at 50 mb/s and upload at 10 mb/s, which is more than enough. But the ping is terrible... A friend told me that he uses a **powerline adapter** that would solve my ping problems but I would have much less download/upload speeds.

Can I use both at the same time, so that I have **low ping and fast download/upload speeds**, without the need of switching between them the everytime?

Comment: What do you consider 'terrible ping'? Is it consistent or intermittent?

Comment: @Tetsujin It's unstable, it jumps to 300ms now and then.

Comment: Why do you think you would have slower speeds on power line? Its certainly possible that powerline won't perform for you depending on your cabling, but its certainly capable of surpassing those speeds.

Comment: @davidgo I borrowed the powerline adapter and tested it today. Even though it was faster than I expected, it was still only a fifth of the speed that the wifi adapter reaches.

Comment: Assuming Power line is not an option, can you advise what wireless gear you are using (both router and your card?  My guess is other devices are intermittently transmitting on your/an overlapping frequency causing bursts of latency.  Changing frequencies might help - particularly if you can use the 5gig band. Directional antennas can help as well.   While it is possible to run both Ethernet and WiFi together its very hard to get right. (And case specific)

Comment: @davidgo I use the D-Link DWA-192 wifi adapter and I use the default router from my provider which is called Vodafone Station (I think it is only used in germany)

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to use the ping from one connection and the bandwidth from another.

A Powerline adapter might work but people tend to have drastically different results from them depending on the wiring in the house, what else is on the circuit, etc.

My recommendation would be to invest in a modern, high quality wifi setup that will serve your work and play activities for years to come.  Some of the new Mesh wifi setups are really good and should get a strong signal to houses of just about any size.

Comment: I thought that maybe it is possible to make windows mainly use the ethernet connection that has good ping and only use the wifi when needing more bandwith. A Mesh wifi setup is a little bit overkill, cause the current wifi is good enough for everything else, but I think I have no choice.

Comment: This is incorrect on many counts. You can have multiple paths between systems, and with work even discriminate on protocol. You can also bond channels to increase bandwidth and WIFI upgrades can often help but are not a panacea and we don't know enough about his setup.